# Displaying the same value in SQL case statement

Tags: sqlite

This might be a simple question but I am unable to find a solution for this, I have a SQL case statement of some form, for example:

```
CASE
  WHEN table_1.col_1 IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
  ELSE table_1.col_1
END as 'col_1'
```

col_1 is of TEXT data type. What I am trying to achieve is that I want NULL to be written wherever the value is NULL and then I want the original value to be displayed if it is not NULL. 
I checked the rest of the query it is fine. Making the ELSE statement to 'table_1.col_1' results in all the NOT NULL values as 'table_1.col_1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Making the ELSE statement to 'table_1.col_1' results in all the NOT
>   NULL values as 'table_1.col_1'

Don't use single quotes because you get a string literal `'table_1.col_1'` and not the value of the column `table_1.col_1`.
In the `CASE` expression that you posted though there are not single quotes around `table_1.col_1` so it should work fine, but this logic can be expressed with `COALESCE()` like this:

```
COALESCE(table_1.col_1, 'NULL') AS col_1
```

Also don't use single quotes for aliases. If needed use backticks or square brackets.